# C++ command line "Operation not allowed in WOW64"

Tags: c++, command-line, wow64

I try to call a system program from my C++ program, with administrator, but i get only this message "Operation not allowed in WOW64".
I have tried the following codes:

```
system("netsh.exe interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.2 216.66.84.42");
```

or

```
CreateProcess(NULL, "netsh.exe interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.2 216.66.84.42", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo)
```

and

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "runas", "netsh.exe interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.2 216.66.84.42", "", NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

if i call in an command line, it works

> netsh.exe interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 192.168.1.2
>   216.66.84.42

What can I do to run a system command from my C++ program.

Why can't I compare C++ System(), CreateProcess() and ShellExecute() with start in a normal command line?

Comment: I'm guessing because the command line is actual 64-bit and not WOW64 (ie 32-bit).  Try compiling your app as 64-bit ...

Comment: _Guess_: build your C++ application as 64-bit binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "WOW64" means is "Windows on Windows 64" or it's the emulator for 32-bit applications.  It looks like you're trying to run a 64-bit process from a 32-bit program (or perhaps vice-versa)